# What does "in his life or in his present errand" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the novel [*The Crystal Man*](http://www.forgottenfutures.com/game/ff9/tachypmp.htm#crystal), in Chapter I, there is this sentence:

> He was not entirely at peace with society: there was something in his life or in his present errand which he desired to conceal.

Please can anyone explain what "present errand" means?
And how can I rewrite this sentence using other words, but with the same meaning?

Comment: Why a downvote on my question? I'm new and I would like to understand the reason. Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Present [errand](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/errand)* here simply means *current task*.